How to Get (Windows Server Host Name or IP) Hyper-V VM Host Name or IP Details from Debian-Based Hyper-V VM
I'm currently running a Debian-based VM on a Windows Server 2022 Hyper-V host. I need to execute some PowerShell commands on the Windows Server from my Debian VM
SSH with PowerShell Remoting
I am using SSH to log into the Windows Server and run the PowerShell command:
But I want to avoid manually providing the Windows Server IP each time and streamline the process of running PowerShell commands from your Debian-based VM.
Typically, I would do something like this:
ssh user@windows-server_ip 'powershell -Command "storcli.exe /c0 /vall show"'


However, I want to automate this process and avoid specifying the windows-server_ip or hostname every time. Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the Hyper-V host's hostname or IP from the Debian-based VM?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I successfully retrieved the Hyper-V VM Host Name from a Debian-based Hyper-V VM.
Since Debian 12 does not hv_kvp_daemon preinstalled, I installed it along with the hyperv package to read the necessary files:
root@DEB-HYPV-Debian12:~# apt-get install hyperv-daemons 
root@DEB-HYPV-Debian12:~# pip install hyperkv

Finally, I ran hyperkv and obtained the following output:
{

"HostName": "WIN-SRGVS7XXXXX",

"HostingSystemEditionId": "79",

"HostingSystemNestedLevel": "0",

"HostingSystemOsMajor": "10",

"HostingSystemOsMinor": "0",

"HostingSystemProcessorArchitecture": "9",

"HostingSystemProcessorIdleStateMax": "0",

"HostingSystemProcessorThrottleMax": "100",

"HostingSystemProcessorThrottleMin": "5",

"HostingSystemSpMajor": "0",

"HostingSystemSpMinor": "0",

"PhysicalHostName": "WIN-SRGVS7XXXXX",

"PhysicalHostNameFullyQualified": "WIN-SRGVS7XXXXX",

"VirtualMachineDynamicMemoryBalancingEnabled": "0",

"VirtualMachineId": "18A2EE6D-B528-4103-A1BF-8B21C9FE324F",

"VirtualMachineName": "Debian12_VM"

}

